# Invalid verify algorithm sha256 error

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

Hi I have configured the node.js app and in most part it is working fine.
But at the last step after logging in I am getting this error : Invalid token: **Unable to verify the ID Token: Invalid verify algorithm sha256**
I can see the gtoken being set. 
But I am running out of ideas about where from the algorithm is getting set. I havn't configured it anywhere , so how am I passing an invalid algorithm ?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you converted the downloaded .p12 key into .pem file, and pass the .pem file when building the GitkitClient?

Comment: yes I have done the conversion using openssl as google suggests https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/quickstart/nodejs. I have built it using node.js.

Comment: The gtoken is signed by the RSA-SHA256 algorithm, and the nodejs app relies on the openssl to verify the signature. Have you installed openssl on your machine?

Comment: Well, thats interesting. I am actually using https://github.com/apigee/trireme to run the node code. It does not use openSSL. Do you think this can be an issue ?

Comment: Probably yes. I am not familiar with trireme, but according to the Crypto section in the github README file, it seems the "trireme-crypto" module is needed:  "Like TLS, certain features (Sign/Verify in particular) only work if the "trireme-crypto" module and its dependencies are in the class path. If they are not present then these methods will throw an exception. This is primarily because the trireme-crypto module uses Bouncy Castle to implement PEM file reading and decryption. It is possible to run Trireme without Bouncy Castle if these features are not needed."